# Form input from index.html with Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, input, shiny

I am trying to use index.html to take in dates and hours from the user and I am having some problems.
For hours as a number the index.html of

```
<input type="number" name="var">
```

and later

```
 Output Text
<pre id="text1" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>
```

and then in server.R

```
data <- reactive({ 
...
dist(input$var)
})

output$text1 <- renderText({
  paste("You have selected", input$var)
})
```

displays the number input back in index.html fine. 
But when I replace the number input type with a date

```
<input type="date" name="var">
```

nothing gets displayed.

Am I going about this all wrong? Any help you can give me or just point me in the right direction would be great.

This question seems close [Button submit R with shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736163/button-submit-r-with-shiny) but a "date" does not seem like a custom input.

Answer (score 0):

`date` and `number` are not input types. you need to use a `text` type.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. text input type works fine. So index.html can take numbers and text but not date? Is this a constraint of Shiny?

Comment: If you want to import a date, you will either have to make each text section on your own (one for year, one for month, etc), but I think jquery also has a solution for that.